# Loader Gif doesn't move while in the mid of ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a loader with id "loading". I hide and show it according to ajax call. It is shown just before the call and after the process. The problem is, it seems standstill or frozen when the request is being processed. Attaching my code

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var desktop = $("#desktop").val();
    var server = $('#server').val();
    var projectid = $('#projectid').val();
    $('#loading').show();
    var url2 = "/micro_workbook_target/Home/UpdateCustom/?ProjectId=" + projectid+"&desktop=" + desktop + "&server=" + server;
    $.post(url2, function (json) {
        var url1 = "/micro_workbook_target/Home/GetJson/?ProjectId=" + projectid;
        $.post(url1, function (json) {
            var t = json;
            hot.loadData(t.data);
            hot.updateSettings({
                columnSorting: true,
                filters: true
            });

            $('#loading').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: What does .loadData and .updateSettings do?
Sounds like you have a sync process going on.
Make sure your #loading gif works too, try calling  $('#loading').show(); in console.

Comment: .loadData loads DOM and .updateSetting updates in the db. Everything works fine. The loader shows up when the ajax is called and also gets hidden after the updated data is loaded. It's just that it gets frozen while the request is being processed.

I have tried setting asynch:true as well..still no luck

Comment: .updateSetting is another Ajax?
Is it async?

Comment: Try to change it to $.ajax() for a clearer flow. Make sure async:true, default is true.

Comment: If your .loadData also uses an extreme amount of resource, I can imagine that stuttering the loading too. Unlikely though. It is also async:true not 
asynch:true